# React Native: this.props.fetchEvents() needs to fire upon application refresh or boot up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native 0.53 that has a payload of `availableEvents` that I need for it to have ready for the user upon boot up or refresh of the application.

Unfortunately, that does not happen until the user clicks on the VIEW DETAILS button of a particular event, by then it's too late; the screen with the details of the event will render to the user with no `availableEvents` because the payload returns after the render.

So I thought perhaps throwing `this.props.fetchEvents()` inside a `componentDidMount()` would suffice, but not exactly sure where to put it to ensure that `availableEvents` data object is already there by the time the user logins in.

So in the production application, the user has to click on EVENTS and it will fire that `this.props.fetchEvents()` and obtain the `availableEvents` object, but in the development app, it defaults to logging the user straight into events and so in development, the user would have to leave the events area and come back, so thats why I am wondering if there is a way in theory that I could call `this.props.fetchEvents()` from the time the user logs into the app and it opens up to events area.

I find that the `fetchFeed()` action creator fires off when the application is refreshed because I decided to pass `dispatch(fetchEvents());` to it and it did load up the `{availableEvents: Array(6), myEvents: Array(0)}` object, but that object is not available to any of the events components until I click on `EVENTS` link in the **Activity Feed** section, which is not helpful because if in dev we had to click on `EVENTS` to get to the events then fine, but in dev environment as soon as I log in, it renders the events feed cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always move your call to get events further up your component tree then pass it down as a prop or if you are using a state management tool like `redux` you can get it out of the application state.

The other option would be to have a conditional render inside of your event details to check if `availableEvents` has a value or a length (not sure if its and object or an array) and if there isn't a value yet render some sort of loading spinner.